# How to optimize this LINQ expression?

Tags: linq, query-optimization

I have this code:

```
var query = from deal in db.Deals
            where deal.EndDate >= DateTime.UtcNow
            select deal;

var priceList = filters.Price.GetPriceRangeList();
foreach(var price in priceList)
{
    var startPrice = price.StartPrice;
    var endPrice = price.EndPrice;
    var priceResult = from deal in query
          where (deal.DiscountPrice >= startPrice && deal.DiscountPrice <= endPrice)
          select deal;
    if(priceResult.Count() != 0)
        priceResults = (priceResults == null) ? priceResult : priceResult.Union(priceResults);
}
query = priceResults != null ? query.Intersect(priceResults) : Enumerable.Empty<Deal>().AsQueryable();
```

My query is slow when priceList has more ten values.

I use Intersect for filters.

How to optimize these queries?

Comment: What is `query`? Btw, you should change `priceResult.Count() != 0` to `priceResult.Any()`. The latter will iterate only one item, whereas the count all.

Comment: LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, etc.?

Comment: I think that my problems with Union

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues. The first one is that the query is executed every iteration in your foreach loop. Calling ToList or ToArray will ensure that it is only executed once
Secondly the union is costly. It will iterate `priceResult` for every iteration of the foreach loop
thirdly your count will also iterate `priceResult`. Use .Any instead if you wish to know if theres any elements. However I think you can avoid that. If I've read your code correctly I believe the below should have the same result but it does not have the above three issues

```
var query = (from deal in db.Deals
             where deal.EndDate >= DateTime.UtcNow
             orderby deal.DiscountPrice ascending
             select deal).ToList();

var priceResults = (from price in filters.Price.GetPriceRangeList()
                    let startPrice = price.StartPrice
                    let endPrice = price.EndPrice
                    select query.SkipWhile(d => deal.DiscountPrice < startPrice)
                           .TakeWhile(d => deal.DiscountPrice <= endPrice)
                    ).SelectMany(x => x);
```

instead of iterating for each union there's a distinct only once

Comment: I can not use "orderby deal.DiscountPrice ascending"
because between these requests I make three such request `if(!filters.City.All && !filters.City.IsEmpty())
            {
                var cities = filters.City.ToArray();
                query = from deal in query
                        where cities.Any(i => i.Equals(deal.City.Name))
                        select deal;
            }`

Comment: And below price PriceResults I make similiar query for Time. So I probably will need to sort each time the required parameter before the main query?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean Victor. If you update your post with the actual code it might help. I'm pretty sute the general Idea still holds. If nothing else you can simply assign the ordered set to a different variable

Answer (score 1):

One idea for optimization would be to sort query by `StartPrice` ascending, that way your inner query can just stop traversal once `StartPrice` is higher than the `DiscountPrice` property:

```
var query = from deal in db.Deals
            where deal.EndDate >= DateTime.UtcNow
            orderby deal.DiscountPrice ascending
            select deal;

..
foreach(..)
{
    var startPrice = price.StartPrice;
    var endPrice = price.EndPrice;

    var queryLocal = query.SkipWhile(deal => deal.DiscountPrice < startPrice);
    var priceResult = queryLocal.TakeWhile(deal => deal.DiscountPrice >= startPrice 
                                      && deal.DiscountPrice <= endPrice);

    ..
}
```

Comment: in your TakeWhile you can skip deal.DiscountPrice >= startPrice that's already quaranteed by the SkipWhile above it